# Completely fire and forget stored procedure C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, asp.net-core

I have a T-SQL stored procedure that is run monthly that takes about 48 hours to complete. I click a button on my client-side application to call a route on my C# .NET Core API. The API then calls the stored procedure. I don't want it to wait in any form or fashion. I added a `Task.Run()` around the function.

```
Task.Run(() => db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.storedProcedure"));
```

This successfully returns a response to the client-side immediately as desired, however, the API is still waiting for this procedure in the background.

Is there a way I can call the procedure and let the API be finished with it completely? I just want to kick it off and let it run purely on the database. For this case, I have no concern with catching errors or other actions that may be considered good practice.

Comment: Avoid having a client to manually create jobs. Consider server side jobs (SQL Server agent, windows schedulled tasks, etc). If yo need to code it, there are good .net schedulers like [quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quartz+%5Bc%23%5D)

Comment: I've tried using Azure runbooks/scheduler to kick off the stored procedure but it seemed to restart the connection every few hours, messing up the stored procedure a fraction of the way through. In addition, users in my organization are choosing when to run the procedure from the client-side. I plan on looking into using a SQL agent.

Comment: There are [Background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in Core, with a sample of [on-demand execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#queued-background-tasks). But ultimately this call will still be terminated if the application restarts for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe create a job in SQL Agent (without an associated schedule) that executes the stored procedure, then from your client application start the job.  Will likely require different privileges but will disconnect your app from the running of the procedure, which sounds like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I will look into this. I'm not familiar with SQL jobs. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: As a bonus feature, if SQL Server Agent jobs fail, you would notice easily, enable email notification on failure, check execution history, etc....

Comment: This may be off-topic, but I would urge looking into what the sproc does, because 48 hours to run is quite a long running task. It may be possible to rework it for performance. Does it even support logging and rollback? I would suggest separating the different tasks into separate units of work.